# handling specific applications volume-level

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, audio, wasapi

Using WASAPI, I could control system volume.
I wonder, I can control the specific application's volume level programmatically. (of course, this is after windows7 only) is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control application (session) volume, just like standard Volume Mixer does it. Read up on this in [Session Volume Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where it is explained pretty detailed:

> WASAPI clients can individually control the volume level of each audio session.
>   [...]
>
> To support this behavior, WASAPI implements the ISimpleAudioVolume
>   interface. When the user moves the application slider, the application
>   calls the ISimpleAudioVolume::SetMasterVolume method to adjust the
>   session volume level accordingly. Sndvol monitors volume changes made
>   through this method and reflects the changes in the volume sliders
>   that it displays.

To discover running sessions, you can use `IAudioSessionEnumerator` interface. Have a look at this code snippet/application implementing the discovery: [AudioSessionVolumeNotification](http://alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/AudioSessionVolumeNotification/AudioSessionVolumeNotification.cpp?rev=165).